# rank function in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, ranking, rank

I have a DB with votes.
I made a sequelize function which count all votes for each answer.
I would like to add a new colonn with the rank depending count. I try to add a Sequelize.Literal () but it doesn't work.

```
await votes.findAll({
      attributes: [
        "answerId",
        [Sequelize.col("answersDb.answer"), "answerText"],
        [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("surveyvote.id")), "count"],
        [Sequelize.literal("(RANK() OVER (ORDER BY count DESC))"), "rank"]
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: modelAnswer,
          as: "answersDb",
          attributes: ["answer"],
        },
      ],
      where: {
        questionId: req.params.questionId,
      },
      group: "answerId",
      order: [["count", "DESC"]],
      raw: true,

    });
```

The error is :

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'count' in 'window order by'
```

I found any solution for my problem. Can you help me ?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Oh yes sorry I forgot ...I add it in main post

Comment: It seems like you need to repeat `COUNT` aggregation in `RANK` `ORDER BY`